# Windows live contacts PHP for 2011

Tags: php, windows-live

I'm currently developing an invite system that is to be integrated into other systems. This development is web based with PHP5. Now i've been looking and testing code for about two weeks but all examples are out-dated and do not work with the windows live 2011. The windows live website itself isn't much of a help.

The login and contacts access requests have to be done trough popup because in my case its not acceptable to let people leave the website to login etc.

So am I just lazy or what is this about?
No, actually I'm not lazy, I did google, I did test etc etc. Just to let you see what I've tried upto sofar:
Out-dated http://livecontactsphp.codeplex.com/
Followed all tutorials at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276466.aspx no luck.
Out-dated http://www.phphulp.nl/php/forum/topic/windows-live-contacts-api/47598/
Out-dated http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wliddev/thread/0087c7f6-d6b7-498e-8c6c-dd95cd2165f8

This list continues for a while.

Anyway, I got a verified domain an full access etc.

Is their anyone with suggestions and/or examples?
Your help is really appreciated

Comment: I've forgotten to tell the core functionality haha sorry,
I've to get contacts out of windows live into our system "contacts grabber / importer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding , what you are trying to do in your web app is to allow the end user to login to his windows live account and after logging in your web app will access his account data .

You need to use Oauth . The tutorial provided here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276466.aspx , is working for me in local host .

But I am not able to access contacts

Comment: I'm somewhat late, but this answer is indeed correct. I didn't check the data that we could get from the windows live API.